# 403 Forbidden and 13 Permission Denied

Tags: linux, redhat, nagios

I am running into a problem of setting up nagios, I followed the quick install guide from http://nagios.sourceforge.net/ but at web interface it prompt 
The pc that is tring to login to the web interface is not a local one, also this happen before prompt to enter username and password.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /nagios on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at xx.x.x.xxx Port 80
```

and

```
[error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx] (13)Permission denied: access to /nagios denied
```

Things I have done to try to resolve it

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/me/nagios
SELINUX=disabled


ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/home/me/nagios/sbin"

<Directory "/home/me/nagios/sbin">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options +ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/me/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>


Alias /nagios "/home/me/nagios/share"

<Directory "/home/me/nagios/share">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/me/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

ls -l /home/me/nagios
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me 4096 Jun  9 13:55 bin
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me 4096 Jun  9 14:42 etc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Jun  9 11:19 include
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me 4096 Jun  9 12:37 libexec
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me 4096 Jun  9 12:35 sbin
drwxrwxr-x 11 me me 4096 Jun 10 10:05 share
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me 4096 Jun 10 11:24 var
```

As well as these are installed

```
Installed Packages
gcc.x86_64                                      4.1.2-55.el5                                           installed
gd.i386                                         2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2                                     installed
gd.x86_64                                       2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2                                     installed
httpd.x86_64                                    2.2.3-91.el5                                           installed
php.x86_64                                      5.1.6-44.el5_10                                        installed
```

Comment: And you restarted Apache after the changes?

Comment: I also want to mention I am using nagios 4.0.8 and nagios plugins 2.0.3

Comment: and yes I restart httpd every time I made a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay solve it...not sure how did a lot of permission given as well as manipulating ipconfig file but something did it

```
give 755 permission to /home/me
add nagios:506:nagios,apache
add nagcmd:510:nagios,apache
```

and then it change to 500 error which I change nagios.conf overide to Indexes and it worked